# Why write struct name twice?

Tags: c

What is the diferrence between these two and how are they used?

```
typedef struct Point
{
    double x;
    double y;
} Point;

typedef struct
{
    double x;
    double y;
} Point;
```

PS: I do not know what search term to use for this. (I'm sure this type of question has been answered before. Kindly add a link to an explanation/answer if known/available.)

Comment: Note that it is permissible to use `typedef struct OneIdentifier { … } CompletelyDifferent;` too. However, C++ automatically makes the name without the `struct` prefix available, so writing `typedef struct SomeName { … } SomeName;` makes `SomeName` available in C — but only after the `typedef` statement is complete, so you can't use `SomeName *member;` in the structure definition, but you must still use `struct SomeName *member;`. Alternatively, use `typedef struct SomeName SomeName;` and then `struct SomeName { …; SomeName *member; … };` to define the structure type. The tag name is required.

Answer (score 2):

A struct declared as the first option can contain a pointer to itself.

You can do this:

```
typedef struct Name {
    struct Name *next;
    // ...
} Name;
```

But not this:

```
typedef struct {
    Name *next;
    // ...
} Name;
```

The `typedef` definition (`Name`, without the `struct` prefix) is only available after the `typedef` is complete. But `struct Name` can be used (though only as a pointer, being an incomplete type) before the `struct` definition is complete.

Comment: Plus, second option is giving a name to an anonymous structure (but after it's been declared), so it can't be referenced inside itself.